# Connection between Purim and Exodus

Tags: purim, moshe-rabbeinu, yetziat-mitzrayim, parashas-shemos, messianic-redemption

It is mentioned in [The Zohar](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Vayishlach.3.74?vhe=Vocalized_Zohar,_Israel_2013&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A9%20%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%20%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%93%20%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91):

לשלש גאולות על ידי שלשה צדיקים משה מרדכי משיח שעתיד לגאלנו בקרוב

Three redemptions, with three righteous leaders, Moshe, Mordechai, and the future Moshiach.

I am looking for other places where a connection (of any sort) is made between Purim and the Exodus.

Comment: e.g. ? https://ohr.edu/6251

Comment: Megillah 6b מסמך גאולה לגאולה עדיף

Comment: Esther's fasts and the showdown with Haman were on Pesach

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that both the Passover/Exodus of Exodus 12 and the Festival of Purim (Esther 9) are examples of our deliverance from a death sentence. A freeing or a reversal of fortune from the bondage and consequences of sin. Both Haman and Pharaoh perhaps represent a shadow/type of the adversary, Satan, in each of our lives. We too have been and are being freed from our own bondage, our own death sentence if you will. Both events are to be remembered perpetually, with great joy, for great is this Deliverer, the Moshiach, that has reversed the curse of sin and death in our own lives. Blessings!

Comment: @msh210 can you have a look at this - "for great is this Deliverer, the Moshiach, that has reversed the curse of sin and death in our own lives" sounds a little odd

Comment: Isn't that the reason for the Festival of Purim? A reversal of the curse? Much as the blood was applied at Passover? It seems to me these are literal people but also types/shadows of deeper spiritual truths. Xerxes, Esther, Mordecai, Haman are all real people but also types are they not? Not meaning to sound odd, just my perceptions, I certainly don't understand everything just offering an opinion re the original question and possible parallels. Blessings!